# How do I populate mongoose schema values from a schema referenced from inside another schema in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a mongoose schema of "products" which includes a array of colors(another schema).
The orders schema contains user and an array of products. The products contain the product, quantity and the color. The color here is the schema which is specific to a product.

I want the user to be able to order a product of a specific color (color which is available for the product)
How do I populate the color of the selected product ?

models\product.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ColorSchema = new Schema({
    value : {type : String} 
});


var ProductSchema = new Schema({
    name:  {
        type: String,
     default: ''
    },
    colors : [ColorSchema] 
 });

 module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);

 module.exports = mongoose.model('Color', ColorSchema );
```

models\order.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var OrderSchema = new Schema({
    timestamp : { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    user : {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'} ,
    products : [{
        product : {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product'},
        color :  {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Color'},
        quantity : Number
        }]

});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Order', OrderSchema );
```

The get Query :

```
function getOrders(res) {
    Order.find({})
    .populate('user')
    .populate('products.product')
    .populate('products.color')
    .exec(function (err, orders) {
        // if there is an error retrieving, send the error. nothing after res.send(err) will execute
        if (err) {
            //console.log("error");
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.json(orders); // return all orders in JSON format
    });

}
```

I have added the entry to the db using postman .
The get Query returns the color field as null.

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5749b94508e742484c13d16e",
    "__v": 0,
    "user": {
          "_id": "57482af31d885d030064f6ff",
          "__v": 0,
          "phone": "9999999999",
          "name": "XYZ"
        },
    "products": [
      {
        "product": {
          "_id": "574957c3935ad71048593879",
          "__v": 0,
          "colors": [
            {
              "value": "Black",
              "_id": "574957c3935ad7104859387d"
            },
            {
              "value": "Gold",
              "_id": "574957c3935ad7104859387c"
            },
            {
              "value": "Silver",
              "_id": "574957c3935ad7104859387b"
            }
          ],
          "name": "Xiaomi mi Note 3"
        },
        "color": null,       // null if I put .populate('products.color')
        "quantity": 5,
        "_id": "5749b94508e742484c13d16f"
      }
    ],
    "timestamp": "2016-05-28T15:29:09.416Z"
  }
]
```

If i remove the .populate('products.color') , It returns the id of the color present in the product.

The User and the product are populated fine. The issue is only with the color, since it is referenced from inside the product.

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5749b94508e742484c13d16e",
    "__v": 0,
    "products": [
      {
        "product": {
          "_id": "574957c3935ad71048593879",
          "__v": 0,
          "colors": [
            {
              "value": "Black",
              "_id": "574957c3935ad7104859387d"
            },
            {
              "value": "Gold",
              "_id": "574957c3935ad7104859387c"
            },
            {
              "value": "Silver",
              "_id": "574957c3935ad7104859387b"
            }
          ],
          "name": "Xiaomi mi Note 3"
        },
        "color": "574957c3935ad7104859387b",  // <-- Id of silver color product if i remove .populate('products.color')
        "quantity": 5,
        "_id": "5749b94508e742484c13d16f"
      }
    ],
    "timestamp": "2016-05-28T15:29:09.416Z"
  }
]
```

I would want the color field to be populated as:

```
"color": {
  "value": "Silver",
  "_id": "574957c3935ad7104859387b"
}
```

Any suggestions on this ?

**Edit:**

The code to add the order is as below:

```
exports.addOrder = function (req, res) {

    var prods_arr = [];

    for(var i = 0, l = req.body.products.length; i < l; i++) {

        prods_arr.push({
            product: req.body.products[i].product,
            color: req.body.products[i].color,
            quantity: req.body.products[i].quantity
            })
        }   


    var order_obj = new Order();
    order_obj.user = req.body.user;
    order_obj.products = prods_arr;

    Order.create(order_obj, function (err, order) {
        if (err){
            res.send(err);
        }
        // get and return all the orders after you create another
        getOrders(res);
    });

};
```

Using Postman , I send the below raw json data as the body of the request.

```
{
    "user": {
          "_id": "57482af31d885d030064f6ff",
          "__v": 0,
          "phone": "9999999999",
          "name": "XYZ"
        },
    "products": [
      {
        "product": {
          "_id": "574957c3935ad71048593879",
          "__v": 0,
          "colors": [
            {
              "value": "Black",
              "_id": "574957c3935ad7104859387d"
            },
            {
              "value": "Gold",
              "_id": "574957c3935ad7104859387c"
            },
            {
              "value": "Silver",
              "_id": "574957c3935ad7104859387b"
            }
          ],
          "name": "Xiaomi mi Note 3"
        },
        "color": {
              "value": "Silver",
              "_id": "574957c3935ad7104859387b"
            },       
        "quantity": 5,
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: How are you adding the `ObjectId` to `products.color` in your `OrderSchema` ? Also I see in `ProductSchema`  your using `colors : [ColorSchema] `,  this is a sub doc pattern not the same as population . Anyways I don't see you saving color. and you might be getting confused between sub docs and interact with different collections(population)

Comment: @jackblank , I have edited the description too include the code for adding the orders and also the request I send using postman